# Why the items crowd together in React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

What happened?? :
[image]
I've tried switching those props like `keyExtractor`/`initialNumToRender`/`windowSize`/ `getItemLayout`, but still not work.

When using `ScrollView` instead of `FlatList`, it will be what I expected:
[image]

Comment: `renderItem({item}=>( <View  style={{height: 200 , marginTop: 20 }} > <Student/></View>))`

Answer (score 0):

I try testing not using `styled-components`, then it works!
I don't know why. (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)
[image]